# Set <div> Height to Bottom of Browser Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While it seems there should be a way to do this, I'm starting to suspect there is not.

I have a content `<div>` located somewhere on my page.

```
+---------------------------+
| Header                    |
+---------------------------+
|         |                 |
| Sidebar | Content         |
|         |                 |
|         |                 |
|         |                 |
+---------+-----------------+
```

What I would like to do is set the height of the content `<div>` such that the bottom is equal to the bottom of the browser window.

I know I can do this with absolute positioning. But is there no way to do this within an existing layout? If the only way is with JavaScript/jQuery, then I'd be interested to see how that might be accomplished.

*Ulimately, my goal here is to make this `<div>` scrollable using `overflow-x: auto`. But I must have a fixed height in order for that to work.*

Comment: Hi, i provided you with a complete solution yesterday there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557666/create-scrollable-element-and-set-size-to-match-window/15557817#15557817 What is wrong with absolute positionning? What is an "existing layout"? Why would the "only way" be with Javascript when this can be solved with pure CSS?

Comment: set height to 100%?...

Comment: I have an existing layout that does not use absolute positioning. So that approach requires me to refactor our entire site's layout. I would love to avoid that. If I can do so in pure CSS then I'd be happy not to use JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: What if your page grows bigger.

Comment: @silentboy: Are you asking what happens if the browser window is resized? If so, that seems like an appropriate question. The page itself won't grow.

Comment: The "pure CSS" solution requires that all ancestors of #content have a defined height and are positionned either relative, absolute of fixed. Let's say `html, body{height:100%;position:relative;}` or `html, body{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0}` for instance. See if you can achieve that in your layout.

Comment: @darma: I understand the issue. Your answer was correct. But I would prefer not to refactor the layout of my entire site. Why go on with additional explanations of what you already said? I get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use javascript here - when the dom is ready set the height of the content to be height of the window - height of the header

```
$('#content').height($(window).height() - $('#header').height());
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of lack informations, like is the height of header fixed, or are there other dynamic divs which could cause problems, one solution which maybe works.

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var resizeDiv = function (object) {
        object.height($(window).height() - $('#header').height());
    };


    $(window).ready(function () {
        resizeDiv($('#content'));
    });

    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        resizeDiv($('#content'));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure css solution:

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

#content{
  //assuming that 80px is the header's height
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 80px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 80px);
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/ihemus/3/

Is this OK?

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}
#sidebar{
  background-color:orange;
  width: 20%;
  float:left;
  height: 100%
}
#content{
  background-color:gold;
  height: 100%
}
```

---

**SOLVED** using table:
http://jsbin.com/ihemus/15/

```
table{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I need some time to look at this.

Comment: I have tired negative margins, to hide the scroll-bar but got no good result... (you can use hidden scroll-bar though)

Comment: Thanks for that, but using a `<table>` would require reworking my entire site layout anyway. So a table layout is not really an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

try in the content div to add a class or a style="min-height:100%",i think it will work.

using JS, lets assume that your content's div has the id="content" and header the id="header", so in jquery,you can do it like that :

```
$("#content").css("height",$(window).height()-$("#header").height);
```

Comment: No, that does not work. Here, 100% refers to the height of the container element and not the browser window.

Comment: min-height would mean minimum 100% of the height of its container... So the header taking some space will make it grow bigger than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var height = height_of_section('div');
document.getElementById('div').style.height = height;

function height_of_section(id)
{
    // elemet position on the window
    var element_position= document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect().top;
    // window scroll y value from top
    var window_scroll = window.scrollY;
    var calc = window_scroll + element_position; 
    return 'calc(100vh - ' + calc + 'px - 40px)';
};
```

```css
#div{
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="div"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Give your header and sidebar a fixed positioning.
Then your content will automatically scroll without header and sidebar.
Can it be a solution?